# Why long URL's and what are those extra characters for?

Tags: php, url, router

I was looking at a few web e-commerce website and noticed that they usually have long URL something like this (taken from an e-commerce site)

```
https://www.example.com/bsquare-tuxedo-solid-men-s-suit/p/itmejr4zbjt6fr3h?gclid=CjwKEAiAz4XFBRCW87vj6-28uFMSJAAHeGZbXBpy4Rw5UckmBAiPaacHLhr5MbPj4bMxVThaQe5A3xoCIi7w_wcB&pid=SUIEJR4ZAK7FZKRT&cmpid=content_suit_8965229628_gmc_pla&tgi=sem%2C1%2CG%2C11214002%2Cg%2Csearch%2C%2C95089233620%2C1o5%2C%2C%2Cc%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&s_kwcid=AL!739!3!95089233620!!!g!182171694500!&ef_id=WJitiQAAAfz4lw1Y%3A20170213091758%3As
```

Generally a router would be

```
http://www.example.com/controller/method/param1/param2
```

Then what all codes go up in the longer URL as above and why do a longer version when a short URL can get the same job done?

Answer (score 0):

You can start to read more about get method:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-get.html

To send data server side in php you will need to make a request get or post. The second link is an get but rewritten.In the end to access your data the url will be rewritten by the framework you use ( http://www.example.com/controller/method?id1=param1&id2=param2 ). If you do not use any framework you will need to rewrite yourself with .htaccess Usually the second link is used for 
more common pages so will be better indexed by google. The first link is for data that is more dynamic and may have more or less parameters, null or "" values etc. And also you do not care to index that page. For exempla a search : http://www.example.com/controller/method?searchValue=&page=1

You also can read more here. It explain how and why we rewrite links: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: what? ... How does the get method relate to the question up top

Comment: You probably did not understand what I asked or I was unable to explain myself. I understand how the GET and POST method works. I do understand the "Pretty URL" too. Thank you again.

Comment: The above URL seem to have 3 to 4 param in it. If this is the case why 3 or 4?. If I need to retrieve an information wouldn't just the ID be good enough? If it is, why all other param.

Comment: The number of parameters depends on the situation. For example an online shop: if you know the exact product is enough id (for a basic site, for more complicated is other story), like you said.

Comment: But let's say that you want a new phone,but not sure what phone you want. You only know that must be white, have more than 16GB memory and touchscreen. For that you will have multiple filters something like this: 

www.example.com/controller/method?category='phones'&color=white&memory='16'&touchscren=true

Comment: After that you remebeer that your friend has iphone and she likes it. You also search for iphone the new url will be
www.example.com/controller/method?category='phones'&color=white&memory='16'&touchscren=true&search='iphone'

After that you decided that iphone may be oki, but maybe not white, you remove the filter for color:

www.example.com/controller/method?category='phones'&memory='16'&touchscren=true&search='iphone'

And so on. In this case would be dificult to make an short url for every filter, because are a lot of combinations.